# The PDA have to finish reading the input?

Tags: automata

I have PDA which has final state that accept 'c' char, and there isn't any cross to other state.
The input abca will accept, because there is 'c', or the PDA would stuck?

Answer (score 2):

I think the PDA would stuck as to accept the input string "abcd", the complete input string needs to be read. But your PDA will work only till 'c' is read and get stuck when it finds another letter 'd', but has no transition state.